# Can google cloud cron jobs be used on a web site?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

I've been trying for a long time, but somehow Google Cloud could not create any cron jobs for my web site.

If you know the correct solution, please tell me:
How would we create the Google Cloud/console /App Engine/cron jobs using PHP?

Comment: This needs more information; Correct solution to what? 
What have you done? 
-What did you try?
Did you google  some keywords on how to use the scheduler?
What did you see when you tried it? What did you try exactly?
Do you got error messages? 
You're question is lacking information. 
We need to know what you did! its not a secret! ;).

https://medium.com/pankaj-khuranas-blog/task-scheduling-made-easy-by-google-cloud-scheduler-a-managed-cron-service-136bdf8b3111

Answer (score 1):

1.Follow the [Quickstart for PHP 7 in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart?authuser=1)

2. After cloning the repository code, list `helloworld` folder:

   ```
   ls
   #app.yaml  composer.json index.php  phpunit.xml.dist  README.md  test
   ```
3. Change the `index.php` to :

   ```
   <?php
   echo "hello world!";
   echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
   http_response_code(200);
   ?>
   ```
4. Add a `cron.yaml` file:

   ```
   cron:
   - description: "every 1 minute summary job"
     url: /
     schedule: every 1 minutes
   # Your application will be called every minute
   ```
5. Deploy the app:

   ```
     gcloud app deploy  -q
     gclod app browse 
     # Go to https://your-project.appspot.com
     # hello world!The time is 10:45:33am
   ```
6. Deploy the cron job:

   ```
     gcloud app deploy cron.yaml -q
   ```
7. Check the logs to see that indeed is working:

   ```
     gcloud app logs tail -s default
     #2020-02-09 10:41:00 default[20200209t112950]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
     #2020-02-09 10:42:00 default[20200209t112950]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
     #2020-02-09 10:43:00 default[20200209t112950]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
     #2020-02-09 10:44:00 default[20200209t112950]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
   ```
8. Check the App Engine Cron jobs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending your GAE application's Environment (Standard/Flexible) you may use these links in PHP Runtime:

- [Scheduling Jobs in Standard Env](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?authuser=1) or
- [Scheduling Jobs in Flex Env](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#cron_support_in_the_console)

in order to to configure regularly scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.

As stated in both documents:

> Free applications can have up to 20 scheduled tasks. Paid applications
>   can have up to 250 scheduled tasks.

I hope this information help.